# Warning NU1605 Detected package downgrade: Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform from 6.0.8 to 5.2.3

Tags: uwp, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I followed the [quick start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-uwp) to download a visual studio project for a UWP application to use Azure AD v2.0 endpoint with Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL) Preview.

When I build I get warning

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning NU1605  Detected package downgrade: Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform from 6.0.8 to 5.2.3. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version. 
 active-directory-dotnet-native-uwp-v2 -> Microsoft.Identity.Client 2.3.1-preview -> Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform (>= 6.0.8) 
 active-directory-dotnet-native-uwp-v2 -> Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform (>= 5.2.3) active-directory-dotnet-native-uwp-v2   C:\azure-samples\active-directory-dotnet-native-uwp-v2-master\active-directory-dotnet-native-uwp-v2\active-directory-dotnet-native-uwp-v2.csproj    1
```

When I look in Nuget Manage Packages for solution there is only one option for Microsoft.Identity.Client which is 2.3.1-preview  and one option for Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform which is Latest stable 5.2.3

The warning repeats when I follow the instructions at the Package Manager Console.

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Identity.Client -Pre
```

I am using Windows 10 1809 with SDK 17763

Comment: which version of Windows 10 are you using? and of Visual Studio?

Comment: That seems to be a build warning, not a build error.

Comment: Thanks , I corrected the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran the app with the warning and it is fine. The auth library uses some very common UWP APIs, so downgrading that package does not affect the experience.

If you want to get rid of the warning, just update Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform to version 6.0.8. I will propose a change to the GitHub repo backing this sample with this upgrade.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but how do I update to 6.0.8 ? It does not appear in Package Manager.

Comment: The warning tells you - "Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version. "